# Mysql php error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect from my PC to a database that is hosted by knowhost.

```
$con = new mysqli('188.214.58.120','user','pass','db');
```

When i compile this it shows me this: `mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`
Where is the problem?

Comment: Your remote hosted database does not allow this user, or maybe any user account, to connect from a remote location

Comment: Have you checked that `knowhost` allows remote db connections?

Comment: the error is self-explanatory.  `knowhost` not allowing remote connection

Comment: @RiggsFolly can i change this from the management of knowHost?

Comment: I dont know! Have you tried?

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is thr problem, they do not have a section where you can manage your mysql .

Comment: The cheaper the hosting, the less facilities they provide. Rule 1 in choosing a host is first to decide what facilities you need then to provide